# How to add a checkbox control in dxdatagrid column header?

Tags: typescript, dx-data-grid

In dxDataGrid, how to add a checkbox control in dxDataGrid column header?

< dxi-column dataField="schemaOnly" caption="Schema Only" [width]="150">
< /dxi-column>